# MVC 3 ajax post not getting checkboxfor checked values

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, checkboxlist

I've already tried everything i know, but still can't get my checkboxlist checked values. I have a nested partial view that render some client info data and allows him to do some inserting. Nothing complicated. However, there's a dynamic list of contracts that is generated for some kind of clients. This is my checkboxlist, the dynamic list. 
While i can get the entire form values, i cannot get any check values from my checkboxes.

Here´s my code:

**ViewModel**

```
public List<TITAContratos> Contratos { get; set; }

public class TITAContratos
    {
        public string NumContrato { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
   <div style="position: static; float: left;" id="debPropContratos">
                <span>Contratos do Cliente:</span> 
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Contratos)
```

**EDITOR**

```
@model MVCGestaoWeb.Models.ViewModels.TITAContratos
<p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NumContrato)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked )
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Checked , Model.NumContrato)
    <br />
</p>
```

SCRIPT

```
$("#btnCadAcordo").click(function () {
            var urlSave = '@Url.Action("DebPropostas")';
            var taVM = $("#debPropForm").serializeObject();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlSave,
                //Com isso ele permite a passagem de objetos para o Controller
                data: JSON.stringify(taVM),
                datatype: "JSON",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (returndata) {
                    $("#containerDebProp").html(returndata);

                }
            });
            return true;
        });

        $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
```

EDIT

Just to point the problem: i can't get any checkbox checked value. Even though i can get my checkboxes hidden value, i cannot get which checkboxes were checked.

Comment: just to be certain here - your problem is in your controller or getting the value in your checkboxes?

Comment: @Adam, the problem is in my controller. No matter what i do, my checkboxes are always false, even the ones that i've checked. And i need to know which checkboxes were checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the additional hidden field generated for each checkbox by the `CheckBoxFor` helper.

How about sending normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded request using the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method instead of JSON:

```
$("#btnCadAcordo").click(function () {
    var urlSave = '@Url.Action("DebPropostas")';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlSave,
        data: $('#debPropForm').serialize(),
        success: function (returndata) {
            $('#containerDebProp').html(returndata);
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

This way you no longer need the `serializeObject` function. Also the `debPropForm` is nowhere to be seen in the code you have shown, make sure this form wraps the editor template and its input fields.

Comment: Woow, this was fantastic! I wonder how do you know these things just looking at some piece of code. Must be the years of experience. And why the serializeObject method lost the auto-generated checkbox checked values?

Comment: @Adriano-RR, it's the years of experience :-)